# How to access variables imported with @use method in sibling imports

Tags: sass

This is my main.scss file.

```
// Main

// Variables (variables.scss)
@use "../../../style/variables" as *;

// Custom Normalize (normalize.scss)
@use "../../../style/normalize";                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                              
// Site header (header.scss)                                                    
@use "sections/header";
```

Variables defined in `variables.scss` are not accessible in `normalize.scss` & `header.scss`. Is there a way to use them inside those files without separate `@use 'variables'` statement?

Or would you just use separate @use method for each file? I am a newbie, so I don't know what's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

### 1. @import

If you use `@import` except `@use` for imports, then you can access variables defined in *variables.scss* inside the *normalize.scss* & *header.scss*.

But it has a disadvantage. It is difficult to trace where your variables and mixins are coming from because `@import` enables an endless chain of imported files. It also allows for overlap and makes it difficult to trace back why your perfect css breaks. This is a problem especially with complex file structures and projects with multiple contributors and global libraries, **which is why @import is no longer recommended by [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)**.

### 2. @use

It also works like @import to break our stylesheet into smaller sections and load them inside other stylesheets. **The key difference is how you access the original files' members.** To do this you will need to refer to the namespace of the original file.

Here's an example of simple SCSS partials.

**_variables.scss**

```css
$primary_color: #000;
```

**_header.scss**

```css
@use 'variables';

.header {
  color: variables.$primary_color
}
```

If you need more info read this article - https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/use-and-import-rules-in-scss/

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: So in my above code, I will have to explicitly `@use 'variables' in both header & normalize file, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to.